# How to priority the click event first

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm doing the cancel uploading if it too long, i decided to use a splashscreen with cancel button

```
<Window x:Class="App.UploadingSplashScreen"
          xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
        mc:Ignorable="d" x:Name="splashWindow"
        WindowStyle="None" ResizeMode="NoResize"
        AllowsTransparency="True" Background="Transparent" ShowInTaskbar="False" Topmost="True"
        xmlns:dx="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/core"
        WindowStartupLocation="Manual" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
    <StackPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <dx:WaitIndicator  x:Name="Indicator" DeferedVisibility="True" >
            <dx:WaitIndicator.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Percentage, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
            AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </dx:WaitIndicator.ContentTemplate>
        </dx:WaitIndicator>
        <StackPanel>
            <Button Content="Cancel" Background="IndianRed" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Click="CancelUpload_OnClick"></Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

When i click the cancel button, the cancel() of cancellation request will be call, but everytime i try, the click event always fire after the request done and i also received the response. How to overcome this problem?

```
        private async void CancelUpload_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //App.CurrentWindow.TokenSource.Cancel();
        App.CurrentWindow.cancelAction?.Invoke();
    }
```

I try to use Action end Invoke it, but there also no hope.
Sample request i make:

```
                    App.CurrentWindow.cancelAction = () =>
                {
                    App.CurrentWindow.TokenSource.Cancel();
                };
                //
                var response = HttpClient.Instance.PostAsync(GetFileRequestUrl(), content, App.CurrentWindow.TokenSource.Token).Result;
                //
                App.CurrentWindow.TokenSource.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
```

Comment: You've forget to share `CancelUpload_OnClick` handler code or any details about code-behind of how you uploading and how it supposed to be cancelled.

Comment: The job to cancel must be a background task or asynchronous. Otherwise, the thread is blocked and the cancellation so be processed after the longrunning job. It would be relevant to know how you run the job and how you have implemented cancellation.

Comment: Thanks for adding "more" context. Those snippets are rarely useful. Now I can see what you are trying to cancel. But your code looks really bad. There shouldn't be any static references. If there was more context like who is calling the CancelUpload_OnClick handler and who is executing the HttpClient then I could make suggestions to improve your code.

Comment: Reusing the HttpClient is fine and the only legal static variable.

Answer (score 0):

You must properly await an async method. When you call `Task.Result` the async method will execute synchronously as the current thread is waiting for the `Result` property to return. Always `await` an `async` method.

Your code looks smelly too. There shouldn't be any static properties or instances involved. You have not shown enough context to understand what you are doing.

```cs
class MainWindow : Window
{
  public static HttpClient SharedHttpClient { get; } 
    = new HttpClient();

  private CancellationTokenSource HttpClientCancellationTokenSource { get; set; }

  private async Task UploadAsync(HttpContent content)
  {
    try
    {
      // CancellationTokenSource implements IDisposable!
      // We must dispose it e.g. via the using statement/expression or a finally block or explicitly.
      using this.HttpClientCancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

      string url = GetFileRequestUrl();

      // await the async method. Now the user can click the button and execute the cancel operation 
      // *while* the upload is running.
      HttpResponseMessage response = await MainWindow.SharedHttpClient.PostAsync(url, content, this.HttpClientCancellationTokenSource.Token);
    }
    catch(OperationCanceledException)
    {
      // Somebody has cancelled the async task.
      // TODO::Perform rollback, cleanup etc.

      // To allow the caller of this operation to handle cancellation too 
      // you can rethrow the exception or swallow it
      //throw;
    }
    finally
    {
      // this.HttpClientCancellationTokenSource is already disposed at this point (using expression).
      // Set variable to NULL so nobody can accidently try to use the disposed instance
      this.HttpClientCancellationTokenSource = null;
    }
  }

  private async void CancelUpload_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    => this.HttpClientCancellationTokenSource?.Cancel();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, i will provide more information about it. The cancel button not on MainWindow but it on UploadSplashScreen which was on another UI thread. The event Cancel also on UploadSplashScreen. I have try your solution but the app like frozen, when i click cancel it stop the application.

Comment: Sounds like you get an exception. What's this exception?

Comment: It's don't throw any exception, the app not crash but it frozen for many minutes

Comment: It can only freeze if you don't await async methods or if you don't move longrunning operations to a background thread. Can you please post a minimal version of your code that freezes the UI? This code should already integrate my suggestions. Then I can review it and help you to fix it. The issue is related to code that you have not shown. My simple example will not freeze the UI. But the example may not reflect the complexity of your use case.

Comment: Also make sure that you don't access the `Task.Result` property as you were doing in your original code. Look at my example. I `await` the `PostAsync` method. `await` will automatically unwrap the result from the Task object. Directly referencing the `Result` property will lead to a frozen UI thread. It can even deadlock the application.